# Why cannot override CSS background color on Bootstrap button?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

### What I want to happen

[image]

### What's actually happening

[image]

I want to toggle the `red-background` class, so that when the mouse hovers over the `button-bullet`, it changes its `background-color` to `#FCC1C5`.

I don't want to use `.btn.button-bullet:hover` because I have some jQuery logic that disables the remove button from showing up when there is only one bullet element on screen.

For some reason, when I `toggleClass("red-background")`, nothing shows up.

I think it might be because in the CSS, I set `.btn.button-bullet`'s  `background-color` to `transparent`. So *if that is the problem*, how do I override the `background-color` in jQuery?

### Code

*HTML*

```
<div class="worksheet-problems">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg worksheet-problem">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-bullet"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-one-fine-dot" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
          </div>
          <input type="text" name="Worksheet-Problem" class="form-control" placeholder="Problem..." aria-label="Write worksheet problem here">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-add" aria-label="Add"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.red-background{
  background-color: #FCC1C5;
}
/*get rid of Boostrap default grey for buttons*/
.btn.button-add, .btn.button-bullet{
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

*jQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".worksheet-problems").on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".button-bullet", function() {
    if ($(".worksheet-problems").children().length > 1) {
      $(this).children(".glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-one-fine-dot");
      $(this).toggleClass("red-background");
      $(this).children(".glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign");
    }
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14ongm/h2m62aan/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem: your `red-background` class has lower specificity than `.btn.button-bullet`.

Solution (add more specificity and place it after selectors with transparent background):

```
.btn.button-add, .btn.button-bullet {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.btn.red-background {
  background-color: #FCC1C5;
}
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, just keep making the button class more specific. .worksheet-problems .btn.red-background etc - the more selectors you add, the higher the priority will be.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
$(this).toggleClass("red-background");
```

ain't the background element. So check which element you're actually altering:

```
console.log($(this));
```

to check that it actually is the right element you want to alter. And a hack 
sometimes, but a lifesafer can be to use :

```
.red-background{
    background-color: #FCC1C5 !important;
}
```

But the problem can also be in that a bootstrap style has higher precendence than you're css class. Make it more specific.

Comment: `$(".worksheet-problems").on("mouseenter mouseleave", **".button-bullet"**...` It's exactly this element.